# Code execution skipped while requesting for token

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I am requesting for token but code doesn't executed on `SendAsync` portion. I am getting token usisng postman successfully.

**`Here is the example snippet:`**

```
                string tokenUrl = $"https://myServiceUrl.cognitiveservices.azure.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken";
                var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);
                tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    ["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    ["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = "MyKey"
                });
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest); // skipped here 

                dynamic json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(json);
```

I even tried without `["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` but doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

It turns out the actual cause for 'skipping' the rest of the method was accidentally not awaiting the call to `GetSpeechServiceToken` in the parent method. This caused the thread execution to continue on the original thread and step out of the method, seemingly skipping the remainder.

OP fixed this by instead calling it like this: `GetSpeechServiceToken().Wait()` instead of `GetSpeechServiceToken()`

If you run into a similar issue, below are some interesting reads by microsoft that go into more detail about asynchronous programming with async/await.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model) explain the concept in more detail, below is an excerpt

> **[What Happens in an Async Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod)**
>
> The most important thing to understand in asynchronous programming is
>   how the control flow moves from method to method. The following
>   diagram leads you through the process.
>
> [image: Example of Async Flow]
>
> The numbers in the diagram correspond to the following steps.
>
> 1. An event handler calls and awaits the `AccessTheWebAsync` async method.
> 2. `AccessTheWebAsync` creates an `HttpClient` instance and calls the
>      `GetStringAsync` asynchronous method to download the contents of a
>      website as a string.
> 3. Something happens in `GetStringAsync` that suspends its progress.
>      Perhaps it must wait for a website to download or some other blocking
>      activity. To avoid blocking resources, `GetStringAsync` yields control
>      to its caller, `AccessTheWebAsync`.
>
>    `GetStringAsync` returns a `Task<TResult>` where `TResult` is a string, and
>      `AccessTheWebAsync` assigns the task to the `getStringTask` variable. The
>      task represents the ongoing process for the call to `GetStringAsync`,
>      with a commitment to produce an actual string value when the work is
>      complete.
> 4. Because `getStringTask` hasn't been awaited yet, `AccessTheWebAsync` can
>      continue with other work that doesn't depend on the final result from
>      `GetStringAsync`. That work is represented by a call to the synchronous
>      method `DoIndependentWork`.
> 5. `DoIndependentWork` is a synchronous method that does its work and
>      returns to its caller.
> 6. `AccessTheWebAsync` has run out of work that it can do without a result
>      from `getStringTask`. `AccessTheWebAsync` next wants to calculate and
>      return the length of the downloaded string, but the method can't
>      calculate that value until the method has the string.
>
>    Therefore, `AccessTheWebAsync` uses an await operator to suspend its
>      progress and to yield control to the method that called
>      `AccessTheWebAsync`. `AccessTheWebAsync` returns a `Task<int>` to the
>      caller. The task represents a promise to produce an integer result
>      that's the length of the downloaded string.
>
>    Inside the caller (the event handler in this example), the processing
>      pattern continues. The caller might do other work that doesn't depend
>      on the result from `AccessTheWebAsync` before awaiting that result, or
>      the caller might await immediately. The event handler is waiting for
>      `AccessTheWebAsync`, and `AccessTheWebAsync` is waiting for
>      `GetStringAsync`.
> 7. `GetStringAsync` completes and produces a string result. The string
>      result isn't returned by the call to `GetStringAsync` in the way that
>      you might expect. (Remember that the method already returned a task in
>      step 3.) Instead, the string result is stored in the task that
>      represents the completion of the method, `getStringTask`. The await
>      operator retrieves the result from `getStringTask`. The assignment
>      statement assigns the retrieved result to `urlContents`.
> 8. When `AccessTheWebAsync` has the string result, the method can calculate the 
>      length of the string. Then the work of `AccessTheWebAsync` is also
>      complete, and the waiting event handler can resume.

[Another article published by microsoft about best practices for async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

### Original Answer

The reason it does't work is because your not calling the endpoint correctly:

You can use either of these endpoints:

`https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/sts/v1.0/issueToken`
`https://myServiceUrl.cognitiveservices.azure.com/sts/v1.0/issuetoken`

And the request can be like this:

```
            var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);
            tokenRequest.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);

            var client = new HttpClient();

            var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

            var result = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The result is already a string with the token value. No need to deserialize it with Json.Net, that'll just cause an exception.

Comment: As I said I am getting token using postman so my service url is absolutely fine. I have tried your code still skipped execution.

Comment: Yes, I understand your service url is fine. It was the code you posted that will not work, since you don't set your `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` Header correctly. My code is tested and will work in normal situations. Is there any error on the 'skipped' line?

Comment: No error actually, just skipping the execution on send async line. Weird.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the next line after sendasync and then inspect `tokenResponse`? Does it contain anything?

Comment: No no breakpoint works just skipped full method without any exception or anything.

Comment: Can you show the calling method? It sounds like you miss an await somewhere, which can mean the call is not awaited and the execution flow continuous before your call to cognitive services is completed.

Comment: Yes, right you were, It was related to await issue. though my method looks like this private `async Task<string> GetSpeechServiceToken()`. While I was calling it like this `GetSpeechServiceToken()` it failed, replaced with `GetSpeechServiceToken().Wait();` now working as expected. It was too silly. Thanks for your tips